# Scrollbars appear on the page with crystal report for VS2010

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I prefer displaying my report in a `div` container which has `overflow:scroll`

I put the crystal report viewer inside the DIV and expect it to remain within the div only which works fine. My div gets scroll bars when the report overflows.

But My page also gets scrollbars when the report overflows !! showing blank space equal to the height of the report.

Somehow the `z-index` of the report does not work as expected. So I tried all my divs in the html with `position:relative` and used higher z-index values up to 1000. But still no luck.

Am i missing something ?

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="divCrt" class="GridTableBorder" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; overflow: scroll;
      position: relative; height: 400px;width: 99%; vertical-align: top; z-index: 800; top: 0px; background-color: #b0c4de;" runat="server">

   <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="Crv" runat="server" Style="width: 98%; vertical-align: top ;       overflow:hidden; " AutoDataBind="true"  DisplayToolbar="False" DisplayPage="true"
Font-Names="Draft 10cpi" BestFitPage="False" >
</CR:CrystalReportViewer>

</div>
```

Expected result : divCrt should scroll but not the page. Same code worked in VS2005,VS2008

Thanks

EDIT : Here is the screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the ScrollBars of your report following these setps.

1. On Visual Studio open your "CrystalReport.rpt" file.
2. Then click "Crystal Reports" from the top menu.
3. Then "Design" -> "Page Setup..."
4. Under "Page Options" there is a drop down menu select "User Defined Size"
5. Then select **"Inches"** and enter your "Horizontal" and "Vertical" size.
6. Click OK

**Important Note:** On Step 5 you have to select "Inches" for some reason the "Pixels" option doesn't work.

These steps are for Crystal Reports Version 13.0.5.891 and if you are using Visual Studio 2010.

Hope this helps.

Pablo